# Highcharts stylemode and colorByPoint

Tags: css, highcharts

I have a Highcharts bar graph and I would like each bar to be red or green, depending if the value is positive or negative. I am using

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
    colorByPoint: true
    }
}
```

and setting the colors I want to use. Without styled mode, the colors work correctly. With styled mode, the colors get overridden by the CSS. How can I use both styled mode and colorByPoint?

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/er1187/gbok7s33/

My colors work only if style mode is commented out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attacking the problem with pure CSS:

- Disable `colorByPoint` option
- Define a standard colour for the series, e.g.

  ```
  .highcharts-color-0 {
      fill: #008000;
      stroke: #004000;
  }
  ```
- Highcharts defines a `highcharts-negative` class for negative figures, so we can override the default colour based on that:

  ```
  .highcharts-negative {
      fill: #800000;
      stroke: #400000;
  }
  ```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbok7s33/6/

**EDIT**: If there's always going to be the same number of datapoints and you want to target a specific one, try re-enabling `colorByPoint` and updating the CSS to:

```
[class^='highcharts-color-'], [class*=' highcharts-color-']{
    fill: #008000;
    stroke: #004000;
}
```

Assuming you want to target point 4, use the following (note, zero-based index):

```
.highcharts-color-3 {
    fill: #000080 !important;
    stroke: #000040 !important;
}
```

NB: `!important` is needed to override the `.highcharts-negative` class.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbok7s33/7/

Comment: thank you, that works! Is it possible to always have category "FOUR" to be blue, regardless if it is negative or positive?